# Can I find Azure role type (worker or web)?

Tags: azure

Is there any way to find the role type (worker or web)? Maybe a managment API?

thanks,
Nava

Comment: Do you want to know it from outside the deployment, or from within a deployment? What Richard suggest will work within a deployment. I don't think there is a way to get it's type from outside a deployment.

Answer (score 1):

The Web Role will have a Sitesroot folder on the E: or F: drive, you could write a few lines of code to see if that folder exists. I can't think of a way through the API.

```
public static bool IsWebRole()
{
    return (System.IO.Directory.Exists(@"E:\sitesroot") || System.IO.Directory.Exists(@"F:\sitesroot"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can parse / sense from the **RoleName** and **InstanceName** from the **GetHostedService**. Make sure you make **embed-detail** = **true** to get details on service's deployments.

More Info : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460806.aspx

Comment: Good answer, as long as you're happy to name your roles according to a  convention.

Answer (score 0):

Using SDK 2.2 i still couldn't find a better and more reliable solution than relying on the role name.

```
public static bool IsWebRole()
{
    var roleName = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Name;
    var match = Regex.Match(roleName, ".*webrole.*?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (match.Success) return true;
    match = Regex.Match(roleName, ".*workerrole.*?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (match.Success) return false;
    throw new Exception(String.Format("Can't figure out role type of {0}", roleName));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is from within deployment. It is worker role if **"WaWorkerHost"** process exists, else it is web role. you can also check **"WaIISHost"** instead.

```
    bool isWorkerRole = false;
    foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("WaWorkerHost"))
    {
        isWorkerRole = true;
    }
```