# Determine Azure Web or Worker role? (Alternate: Determine if running in IIS?)

Tags: c#, azure, environment, azure-worker-roles, azure-web-roles

I have some code that I use in both my Worker Role and Web Role start-up code. In the Worker, the code is called from the `Run()` method; in the Web role, it is called in `Application_Start`.

I want to make slight changes to its behavior depending on whether I'm on a worker or web role. Is there a way to detect this? If not, alternatively can I detect if I'm running under IIS?

Note that checking the `HttpContext` won't work since I'm running in `Application_Start`.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using the Run() method for both your web and worker situation? A web role is just a worker role with IIS turned on; the fabric will still call all the RoleEntryPoint (Azure role lifecycle) methods on a web role.

Comment: @ChrisJ.T.Auld Run() doesn't run in the same AppDomain on a Full IIS web role.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I find Azure role type (worker or web)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877461/can-i-find-azure-role-type-worker-or-web)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

This question has [been asked over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877461/can-i-find-azure-role-type-worker-or-web) and over again. What can I think of, is using the approach for [listing all sites in current role instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348359/get-all-sites-defined-in-servicedefinition-for-azure) (the ServerManager approach). If the call to ServerManager fails, or there are no sites at all, then you are in a worker role. Otherwise - web role. I think this is the most reliable way to check.

Do not forget that IIS still exists in the Worker Roles (you can RDP to any worker role and will see that IIS Server Role is present). It is just not started! So a "Default Web Site" might still be there (never checked that one!).

Comment: "over and over again" but you link to a single question with no accepted answer.. just calm down and help the asker solve his problem, no need to be a jerk about it

Answer (score 0):

It is worker role if **"WaWorkerHost"** process exists, else it is web role. you can also check **"WaIISHost"** instead.

```
    bool isWorkerRole = false;
    foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("WaWorkerHost"))
    {
        isWorkerRole = true;
    }
```